# Android realtime add button

Tags: android, button, addition

I need a button that, when clicked, would add a TextView below it. Also, the TextView cannot be made invisible and appear on click in this case, it must add the TextView. Was looking for this and couldn't find anything that suits my needs.

Comment: What container is the button in? Please show your `layout.xml`

Comment: Really? You could not find the set of overloaded `addView()` methods?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/AddProject"
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="StartProject" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: i dont know how to use them, im pretty fresh to this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a listener on the button and for each click, create a new TextView and add it to the layout.

```
final LinearLayout theLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.thelayout);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tv.setText("Hello");
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            theLayout.addView(tv);

        }
    });
```

Update: Added text color above

Comment: Umm ran into a little problem. I cant get the TextView to appear below the button. Any suggestions? :/

Comment: Is the text color the same color as the background?  Try setting layout parameters for the textview, and a style for the color and size.

Comment: Added the text color above.

Comment: I've set the layout parameters and everything's fine. Thanks again.